# Clear memory in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, loops, crash

I have a Big loop is crashing chrome, it iterates over 100,000 times, however each iteration  has a second delay, so the loop can day's to complete (yes I should be doing this server side but this app isn't hosted).

Basically this loop was going to build a big string to download into a csv, however it never got that far, it crashed around the 9,000 mark (no where near the target).

1. I've tried checking if the iteration is perfectly divisible by 5000, and then downloading a file, then resetting the variable to empty before continuing on to 5001.
2. I've tried saving the string to the browser as html, then when the iteration is perfectly divisible by 5000, query the div html and downloading a csv, then clearing the div.

Both solutions still end up crashing chrome.

I'm assuming that this is because it's hitting a memory limit, my question is, is there a way to clear the memory WITH javscript? (so that I can get to 5000 and then clear it?) or at least clear the memory of certain things? (like the variable I'm resetting etc).

The crash isn't particulary helpful, it just say's "Oop's, something has gone wrong"

I'm stuck here, any solutions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you use this browser as a crawler - or so I assume. In large loops, the problem of this component is the time interval between subsequent page loads. I do not know exactly what the cause is, but I solve it so that before the next readings I wait some time - usually 2 to 5 seconds. At this time, the browser appears (after logs) to read the components to the end and prepare for the release of the memory before the next page. I'm using the TChromium component.

Answer (score -2):

Try this link

```
http://theotakukid.com/2011/04/how-to-purge-your-chrome-memory-from-sluggish-performance/
```

Or

And you can also remove your chrome history and restart your browser it will work also
use this shortcut :ctrl+H  and remove the history

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I need to do this in javascript, as It's during a loop that I need to clear everything. I have updated my question